# How to get JavaFx TabPane title to be WebView's site title?

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I am using JavaFx, and have Tabs with WebView objects on them. I am trying to have my tab title's text to read the web page's title like in most web browsers. When I use the "getTitle" method I get an empty title, Which I assume is because the page hasn't loaded yet. All the research I've done gives me an Android Solution and I'm looking for something that works with a desktop application. Here's what I have.

```
public class WebsiteTab extends Tab {

    final static String DEFAULT_SITE = "https://google.com";

    VBox browserBox;
    WebView webView;

    public WebsiteTab() {
        super("Site One");
        webView = new WebView();
        webView.setPrefHeight(5000);

        goToSite(DEFAULT_SITE);

        browserBox = new VBox(10,webView);
        VBox.setVgrow(browserBox, Priority.ALWAYS);

        setContent(browserBox);
    }

    public void goToSite(final String site) {
        webView.getEngine().load(site);
        setText(webView.getEngine().getTitle());
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind the tab's `text` property to the web engine's `title` property.

```java
public class WebsiteTab extends Tab {

    final static String DEFAULT_SITE = "https://google.com";

    VBox browserBox;
    WebView webView;

    public WebsiteTab() {
        super("Site One");
        webView = new WebView();
        webView.setPrefHeight(5000);

        textProperty().bind(webView.getEngine().titleProperty()); // bind the properties

        goToSite(DEFAULT_SITE);

        browserBox = new VBox(10,webView);
        VBox.setVgrow(browserBox, Priority.ALWAYS);

        setContent(browserBox);
    }

    public void goToSite(final String site) {
        webView.getEngine().load(site);
    }
}
```

This will cause the `text` property to always have the same value as the `title` property. In other words, when the `title` property's value changes the `text` property will be automatically updated. Notice I bind the properties in the constructor as you only need to create the binding once. Also note that while bound you can no longer manually set the `text` property; attempting to do so will cause an exception to be thrown. For more information, see [Using JavaFX Properties and Binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm).